# Java hash whose key is a enum type, and values is a unique list of K,V pairs

Tags: java, dictionary

I need a java dictionary that would be like (C# representation):

```
Dictionary<SomeEnumType, List<int, long>>
```

So I want to use it like this:

```
List<int, long> v1 = myDic[SomeEnumType.Value1];

foreach(int i in v1)
{
    long l1 = v1[i];
}
```

And the List should be unique based on the int value.

What java structure supports the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use something like this:

```
HashMap<SomeEnumType, HashMap<Integer, Long>>
```

You would not want to use `List` because it stores single items whereas you want a collection of key-value pairs or mappings. A `HashMap` will only store objects for unique keys. In this case, the inner `HashMap` will store only unique integers and the outer `HashMap` will store only unique Enum types. You can look at the different available implementations of `Map` to see which one will best suit your needs.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1):

You want a `java.util.Map` (common implementations: `TreeMap` and `HashMap`).

A `Map` is a one-to-one mapping from one object type to another - like a dictionary!